# Why Python is returning integer instead of string

Tags: python, string, class, object, integer

```
class Clock(object):
    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time
    def print_time(self):
        time = '6:30'
        print(self.time)

clock = Clock('5:30')
clock.print_time()
```

Why does it print `5:30` instead of `'5:30'`?

Comment: `5:30` is not an integer.

Comment: quotes aren't part of a string, `5:30` is not an int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write a python program, strings need to be placed inside quotes so that the parser knows they are strings. So, you type

```
>>> time = 5:30
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    time = 5:30
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> time = '5:30'
>>>
```

But python doesn't really store the quotes themselves in the string. It creates an object of type `str` whose value is `5:30`. When you print the string, it prints the value, not the quoted representation needed to get the python parser to work.

Python objects have two methods for displaying themselves. `__str__` returns the expected human-readable string while `__repr__` returns a programmer-friendly string that usually includes type information. For a string, it includes the quotes. If you really want the quotes for some reason, you can use `repr`

```
>>> time = '5:30'
>>> print(time)
5:30
>>> print(type(time))
<class 'str'>
>>> print(repr(time))
'5:30'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`""` and `''` are simply delimiting a string, they are not a part of it and therefore won't be printed.
The program is properly printing the string here. (`5:30` is not an integer anyway)

PS: I don't know if `time = '6:30'` in `print_time` is supposed to change the time attribute in `Clock` but if is, it should be `self.time = '6:30'`. The current instruction does not have any effect.